# How to set group id on execution bit (s) permission using java

Tags: java, posix, file-permissions

I'm trying to set the next set of posix permissions `rwxrwsr-x` to a folder that I'm creating in java, but haven't had success on this. I tried the next code:

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> posixPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwsr-x");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(someDir, posixPermissions);
```

but I'm getting the next Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mode
```

I spent some time looking for a way to do this, but I couldn't find anything. I know I can use `ProcessBuilder` class to run a command in the OS to set those permissions, but I wanted to do this purely in Java.
I need to set those permissions so any file created inside that directory "inherits" the group of the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermissions.html#fromString%28java.lang.String%29) you are only allowed to use the characters 'r','w','x' and '-'. But in your code snippet you are using 's', which is illegal of course. It should be like this to work:

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> posixPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxr-x");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(someDir, posixPermissions);
```

Setuid (+s) ist not possible in pure Java, because it's a OS-specific feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Previously I didn't read completely the documentation describing the valid characters. Anyway, I will accept your answer because of this:
"Setuid (+s) ist not possible in pure Java, because it's a OS-specific feature."